# Sql: Show largest cities in each country

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

This question is referring to the 'world' database.

There are two tables: 'City' and 'Country'. City contains fields of population and country code - Ex: 'IND' for India - for each row(city name). Country contains the fields of country code and continent for each row(country name).

I need to get a list which shows the largest city in each country, largest being the one with the largest population. How to do this in MySQL?

Comment: This is basic stuff. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

With mysql (only) there is a trick you can use:

```
select * from (
  select * from
  from country c
  join city d on d.country_id = c.id
  order by population desc
) x
group by 1 -- assumes id column of country table is column number 1
```

Rather than returning an *aggregate* for each group, this non-standard grouping (not all non-aggregated columns are grouped by) returns the *first* row for each group, so by ordering first, you get the largest population city for each country.

Although "officially" not guaranteed to work, in practice it works 100% of the time.

Comment: I would just like to add that your group by is out of scope for c.id.. You may want to select it with an alias to group by :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell how's that change for cheeky?

Comment: Well before it was group by c.id now its group by 1 so that's fixed :).. One other issue you could possibly have is if there are duplicate columns inside the subquery like an id for each table then the select * will throw an error :) +1 from me though

Comment: @JohnRuddell fyi. no error [when there are duplicate column names](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214db/26)

Comment: bohemian thats not the case i was referring to... if two tables have an id field and you do and outer select on the two id's... aka. `SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM t JOIN t1 on t1.id = t.id)` [**it will throw an error**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77e90b/2)

Comment: This method is non-standard SQL, non-deterministic, and perhaps unsafe. Another limitation is that it will only return one city per country. There could be more than one largest city in a given country.

Comment: @sqlvogel is it *really* non-deterministic? If you can show me just one case where is does not return the *first* row encountered for each group then I'll listen. The documentation is just a disclaimer allowing future implementations to vary, but so far every release behaves like this. It is in *reality* deterministic. Regarding ties, true: This technique won't return ties, although the question said "the largest **city** in each country" (not "the largest **cities** in each country"). All that said, it's good that you are keeping me honest.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT country, city
FROM city AS c
WHERE population = (SELECT MAX(population) FROM city WHERE country=c.country);
```

Note that there could in principle be more than one largest city in a country, i.e. two or more cities that happen to have the same population.